# Is there a fast and easy way to solve $x^7-10=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I came across the polynomial equation $$x^7-10=0$$ and by using a calculator, i found its solutions to be very interesting, in fact all of them are of the form $$x=\sqrt[7]{10}e^{\pm \frac{2k i \pi}7}$$ for $k=0,1,2,3$$. 
So, first, i would like to know if there is anything special about this polynomial? And second, can we actually solve it with using a faster method than polynomial division?

Comment: Can you tell what is I in that exponential?

Comment: Are you aware about complex roots?

Comment: If $\omega$ is a primitive 7th root of unity, for example $\omega = \mathrm{exp}( 2 \pi i / 7)$, then $10^{\frac{1}{7}} \omega^j$ will always be a root for any $j$. This also gives all the roots, as $j$ varies over $0,1,\ldots,6$.

Comment: It's the imaginary unit, sorry this was an auto correct error.

Comment: Of course $x = \pm10^{1/7}$ is a solution. Notice that $x = (-1)^{n\,+ \,n/7}10^{1/7}$ are also solutions for natural $n$ such that $n\in[0, 7]$.

Comment: Not $-10^{1/7}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to $\exp(2n \pi i)=\cos(2n \pi ) + i \sin (2n \pi)=1$,
$$x^7 = 10=10\exp(2n\pi i)$$

Hence

$$x=10^{\frac17}\exp\left(\frac{2n \pi i}7 \right)$$

If we draw the argand diagram, the solutions fall on the circle centered at origin with radius $10^\frac{1}{7}$ and evenly spread out and one of the point is positive.